# Angular How to make [formControl] an optional field

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular you can add attributes to inputs and make them optional using attr:

```html
<input [type]="text" [attr.id]="id">
```

But how do you make a form control optional? I want something like this:

```html
<input [type]="text" [attr.formControl]="someControl">
```

Where the formControl will not be set if someControl is undefined or null?

Comment: I fail to understand what you want to achieve. What would be the point of an input field in your page being there but not being bound to any form control, and thus doing nothing?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve by doing so ? whats the use of to make filed form-control optional ? are you trying to create formControl dynamically ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a component that takes inputs and dynamically generates an input field. The input field should be flexible enough to be used either for template or model driven.

Comment: "to be used either for template or model driven" -- Are you aware of `ControlValueAccessor`?

Answer (score 1):

As long you do not attach a required Validator to a formControl it is considered optional in the form. Your form will not have any error for such fields since there is no required Validator attached to them. It is attached like this:

```
firstName: ['', Validators.required],
```